# Safe Zone vs Magic Cylinder

Tags: yu-gi-oh

1. Player A's monster attacks player B's monster.
2. Player B activates Magic Cylinder.
3. Player A activates Safe Zone on his own monster.

**Q**: The attack will not be negated because Safe Zone prevents targeting the monster, right? And since attack is not negated, Magic Cylinder doesn't inflict damage to Player A's life points, right?

[Magic Cylinder](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Magic_Cylinder):

> When an opponent's monster declares an attack: **Target** the attacking
>   monster; negate the attack, and if you do, inflict damage to your
>   opponent equal to its ATK.

[Safe Zone](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Safe_Zone):

> Activate this card by targeting 1 face-up Attack Position monster on
>   the field; that face-up monster **cannot be targeted** or destroyed by
>   your opponent's card effects, or be destroyed by battle. It cannot
>   attack your opponent directly. When this card leaves the field,
>   destroy that monster. When that monster leaves the field, destroy this
>   card.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specific situation you mention does not work out no. Targeting happens at the moment of activation of a card or effect. It's only after that, that you get to chain anything.
So this means that when player B activates magic cylinder, it's already too late.

However, if player A already had Safe Zone active, player B would not be allowed to play Magic Cylinder.

Comment: Correct, the targeting was done before Safe Zone took effect, so it won't save it.